# Getting error when launching app on simulator

Tags: ios, react-native

when running 'npm run ios' i cant install my app on simulator

info Found Xcode workspace "exampleapp.xcworkspace"
info Launching iPhone 12 (iOS 15.2)
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace exampleapp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme exampleapp -destination id=A920E83F-83A2-4F8A-A40C-C5464A9FABDD")
success Successfully built the app

error Failed to launch the app on simulator, An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=405):
Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown

Answer (score 0):

i just run again 'npm run ios' and it worked! Don't know what happened